# avro object not serializable as a value of a Map - Spark

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, avro

I'm facing a strange behaviour.

Spark cannot serialize an avro object inside a Map[String, AvroObj], even after I used avro-1.8.0 which makes avro objects serializable.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: my.avro.Object
    Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: my.avro.Object, value: {"A": "B", ...})
        - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap)
        - object (class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
```

I suspect that the SCHEMA$ attribute is still not serializable, but when I use my AvroObj alone inside a closure, everything works well. In addition, I broadcast my Map[String, AvroObj] without problem too. Again, my avro object only contains String and long.

Then, to handover with that I have to rebuild a new Object extending serializable from my avro ones, and then my new Map[String, MySerializableObject] has no problem... but I lost the usability of classe generation from avsc and it adds a lot of code.

Please, note that I use KryoRegistrator, spark-1.5.0, avro-1.8.0 and scala 2.10.

I tried to set the map as immutable, or even the map(identity) as described here https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7005

Is there a way to by pass this problem without having to redefine a new object ? Or may I have missed something ?

Thank you a lot,
Sebastien

Answer (score 1):

This problem relates to Avro schema compiler any version less then 1.8. Avro generates Java classes without implementing `Serializable` interface, hence such Java objects cause `NotSerializableException` at Spark, when it attempts to serialize them. 
The problem was resolved in Avro 1.8.0 (22 January 2016)

```
AVRO-1502. Java: Generated classes now implement Serializable.
Generated classes need to be regenerated to use this release.
```